# Javafx change tableview cell back color

Tags: mysql, javafx, tableview

I want to create hotel software system.

#### Screenshot of the app

[image: this is screenshot of my app]

I have created FXML page. It has a `TableView` named `tablesettings`.
On `initialize` method of the controller class firstly I add the columns to `tablesettings` and then add the rows.

Now I need to change single cell backcolor by index of columns and rows.
I want a view like this:

[image: desired result]

My Java  code:

```
@FXML
private TableView tablesettings;
   
public void getDatasReserv() {
      ArrayList<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
      ArrayList<String> dts = new ArrayList<String>();
      ArrayList roomss = new ArrayList();
      ArrayList roomtypes = new ArrayList();
      LocalDate localDate1 = girissene.getValue();
      LocalDate localDate2 = cykyssene.getValue();
      Date DPCurrentDate1 =  Date.valueOf(girissene.getValue());
      Date DPCurrentDate2 =  Date.valueOf(cykyssene.getValue());
      dts.add("Otag");
      dts.add("Görnüşi");
      dts.add(localDate1.toString());
        
      while (!localDate1.equals(localDate2)) {
         dates.add(localDate1);
         localDate1 = localDate1.plusDays(1);
         dts.add(localDate1.toString());
      }
        
      // add columns
      for (int i = 0; i < dts.size(); i++) {
            final int finalIdx = i;
            TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> column = new TableColumn<>(dts.get(i) );
            column.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(param.getValue().get(finalIdx)));
            column.cellValueFactoryProperty();
            if(i==0)
                column.maxWidthProperty().set(25);
            if(i==1)
                column.minWidthProperty().set(150);
            else
                column.minWidthProperty().set(80);
            tablesettings.getColumns().add(column);
      }
        
      try {
            connected();
            String sql = "SELECT * from roomsview";
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            while(rs.next()){
                 roomss.add(rs.getString(1)); 
                 roomtypes.add(rs.getString(2));        
            }
            closed();
      } catch (Exception e) {}
         
      Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
          
      data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
      item = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
      // add data
      for(int j=0 ; j<roomss.size(); j++){
            //Iterate Row
             String strs= (String) roomss.get(j);
               int y = Integer.parseInt(strs);
            map.put(y,j);
            ObservableList<Object> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for(int i=1 ; i<=dts.size(); i++){
                //Iterate Column
                 if(i==1){
                     String str= (String) roomss.get(j);
                     row.add(str);
                 }
                 else if(i==2){
                     String str= (String) roomtypes.get(j);
                     row.add(str);
                 }
                 else{row.add("");}
            } 
            data.add(row);
      }
      tablesettings.setItems(data);
      tablesettings.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
      tablesettings.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
      //*****

      ObservableList<Object> row2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
      try {
            connected();
            String sql = "SELECT `20`.startdate, `20`.enddate, `20`.number FROM `20` WHERE `20`.startdate BETWEEN '"+new java.sql.Timestamp(DPCurrentDate1.getTime())+"' AND '"+new java.sql.Timestamp(DPCurrentDate2.getTime())+"'"
                     + " AND `20`.enddate BETWEEN '"+new java.sql.Timestamp(DPCurrentDate1.getTime())+"' AND '"+new java.sql.Timestamp(DPCurrentDate2.getTime())+"'";
             ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
             while(rs.next()){
               //   item.addAll((ObservableList[]) tablesettings.getItems().get(map.get(rs.getInt(3))));
               row2.add(tablesettings.getItems().get(map.get(rs.getInt(3))));
              
             }
             closed();
           
      } catch (Exception e) {}
         
}
```

Mysql database schema only reservation table

```sql
CREATE TABLE `reservation` (
  `reservid` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `roomid` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `guestid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `startdate` date NOT NULL,
  `enddate` date NOT NULL,
  `price` varchar(500) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Дамп данных таблицы `reservation`
--

INSERT INTO `reservation` (`reservid`, `roomid`, `guestid`, `startdate`, `enddate`, `price`) VALUES
(50, 149, 1, '2016-07-16', '2016-07-17', '655'),
(51, 127, 2, '2016-07-15', '2016-07-23', '2400');
```

I would be very happy if you help............

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `cellValueFactory` of your columns should be

```
column.setCellValueFactory(param -> Bindings.valueAt(param.getValue(), finalIdx));
```

Otherwise changes in the lists won't trigger an update of the `TableView`.

To add color to the cells, change the element type of the rows to some class that contains properties that allow you to determine the background and the text. Example:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TableView<ObservableList<ColoredItem>> table = new TableView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(new ColoredItem("1"), new ColoredItem("2", Color.GREEN)),
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(new ColoredItem("3", Color.RED), new ColoredItem("4"))
    ));

    List<String> dts = Arrays.asList("column 1", "column 2");

    for (int i = 0; i < dts.size(); i++) {
        final int finalIdx = i;
        TableColumn<ObservableList<ColoredItem>, ColoredItem> column = new TableColumn<>(dts.get(i));
        column.setCellValueFactory(param -> Bindings.valueAt(param.getValue(), finalIdx));
        column.setCellFactory(tv -> new TableCell<ObservableList<ColoredItem>, ColoredItem>() {

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(ColoredItem item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                if (empty || item == null) {
                    // remove background and text
                    backgroundProperty().unbind();
                    textProperty().unbind();
                    setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    // bind background and text to the item properties
                    textProperty().bind(item.valueProperty());
                    backgroundProperty().bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> new Background(
                            new BackgroundFill(item.getBackground(),
                                    CornerRadii.EMPTY,
                                    Insets.EMPTY)),
                            item.backgroundProperty()));
                }
            }

        });
        table.getColumns().add(column);
    }

    Button btn = new Button("change");
    btn.setOnAction(evt -> {
        table.getItems().get(0).set(0, new ColoredItem("42", Color.YELLOW));
        table.getItems().get(1).get(0).setValue("99");
        table.getItems().get(1).get(0).setBackground(Color.DARKMAGENTA);
    });
    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(table, btn));

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

```
public class ColoredItem {

    public ColoredItem(String value, Paint backround) {
        this.background = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(backround);
        this.value = new SimpleStringProperty(value);
    }

    public ColoredItem(String value) {
        this(value, null);
    }

    private final StringProperty value;
    private final ObjectProperty<Paint> background;

    public final Paint getBackground() {
        return this.background.get();
    }

    public final void setBackground(Paint value) {
        this.background.set(value);
    }

    public final ObjectProperty<Paint> backgroundProperty() {
        return this.background;
    }

    public final String getValue() {
        return this.value.get();
    }

    public final void setValue(String value) {
        this.value.set(value);
    }

    public final StringProperty valueProperty() {
        return this.value;
    }

}
```

---

Also: Don't use raw types if you can avoid it. By specifying the type parameters the compiler can do some checks that could prevent errors at runtime. Furthermore that way you don't need to write down the type casts yourself (e.g. `String str= (String) roomtypes.get(j);` could be written as `String str= roomtypes.get(j);`).

Comment: rows values not added. Error....... Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to ......... It show this line........  column.setCellFactory(tv -> new TableCell<ObservableList<ColoredItem>, ColoredItem>() {

Comment: @Gpear: I guess you haven't changed the type used for the cell values to `ColorItem`, but kept the `String`s so `TableView` tries to call cast the `String` value to `ColorItem` to pass it to the `updateItem` method which doesn't work. I've tested my sample code and it works without this exception. I didn't want to simply write down the solution for your special case, since that would make the code harder to understand for everyone else. Probably everything you have to do to fix the issue is replacing the `row.add(someString);` calls with `row.add(new ColoredItem(someString))`

Comment: it works. But tableviews selected cell color missing. Borders also missing. How can i solve this.

Comment: @Gpear: This is a bit complex, since you need to create a binding to the selected property of the cell if you want to support a arbitrary number of colors. However if you only want to support only a limited set of colors to indicate certain states (e.g. clear/reserved/highlighted or something like that), CSS could be used to easily manipulate the background. If this is the case, please add this info to your question and tell me in a comment and I'll update the answer.